# BigQuery error: AttributeError: 'ClientOptions' object has no attribute 'api_audience'

Tags: google-bigquery

I keep receiving this error `AttributeError: 'ClientOptions' object has no attribute 'api_audience'` once I call the `to_dataframe()` on the query result from BigQuery. This worked fine before using the same virtual env and not sure what's happening now.

`query.result()` didn't raise errors but `query.to_dataframe()` raised the error.

These are the packages I have:

```
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-bigquery==2.34.3
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.16.2
google-cloud-core==2.3.2
google-cloud-storage==2.7.0
```

Comment: What is the version of your `google-api-core`? Have you tried upgrading it to the latest version which is `2.11.0`?

Answer (score 1):

the error may be related to version incompatibility between the google-cloud-core package and other Google Cloud packages.

there are two ways to  solve that  error

> `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-core`

and the other one is a

> `pip install google-cloud-bigquery==2.29.0`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your error and this is when I downgraded my `google-api-core` package to `2.7.3`.

[image]

This can be resolved by upgrading your `google-api-core` to `2.8.0` and up. But the **BEST PRACTICE** is to always keep your packages to the latest version. You may upgrade your package to latest version by running below command.

```
pip install google-api-core --upgrade
```